# How to deploy a Spark app to a remote HPC system?

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I have installed, configured Spark, and developed a parallel algorithm for a maximum clique detection ( a `maxClique.py` file ) on my laptop.

Clique detection is an NP-hard problem, computational challenge.

Could you help guide me step by step to config and deploy the `maxClique.py` from my laptop to a remote cluster at center of high performance computing. http://www.sdsc.edu/services/hpc/hpc_systems.html

Thanks for your helps

Comment: What exactly is _"remote HPC system, cluster thousand cores at my university."_? Could you edit your question and add more details about the HPC system? Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski edited, thanks

Comment: HPC system is simply a pool of hardware, isn't it? If so, you'd have to talk to the admins if they use something atop that manages the pool of hardware resources, e.g. Mesos, DC/OS, YARN, Kubernetes. Spark supports them. You could also use [Spark Standalone](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).

Answer (score 1):

As defined above,
each HPC supercomputing centre,
the SDSC centre included,
operates also Support service lines for helping the applicants to embark the computing jobs in the best-practices manner, fine-tuned per respective HPC-centre local practices, to get executed on their managed computing HPC fabric.

### Kindly follow the SCSC Support directions:

> **Technical Consulting**
>
> SDSC Consultants have experience in computational science and engineering on a variety of vector and parallel platforms. Our consultants are available to assist users with issues related to SDSC computational resources. Users are encouraged to investigate our 'Helpful Tools' section before submitting questions to SDSC Consulting:
>
> - [**User Guides**](http://www.sdsc.edu/support/resource_docs.html) - for all SDSC machines, information for new users, advanced programming articles.
> - Submit a Ticket or **[E-mail](http://mailto:consult@sdsc.edu)** consult@sdsc.edu 9am - 5pm Pacific Standard Time.
> - Call 1-866-336-2357 (9am - 5pm PST for regular inquiries; 24/7 for emergency support only).